# Jquery Carousel Looping

Tags: jquery

Can you help me loop this carousel? I just don't know much about jquery and it's properties. I am afraid if I mess with it without knowing, it will be all messed up. I got this from a template I bought.

```
/*!
 * jCarousel - Riding carousels with jQuery
 *   http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2006 Jan Sorgalla (http://sorgalla.com)
 * Dual licensed under the MIT (http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php)
 * and GPL (http://www.opensource.org/licenses/gpl-license.php) licenses.
 *
 * Built on top of the jQuery library
 *   http://jquery.com
 *
 * Inspired by the "Carousel Component" by Bill Scott
 *   http://billwscott.com/carousel/
 */

/*global window, jQuery */
(function($) {
    // Default configuration properties.
    var defaults = {
        vertical: false,
        rtl: false,
        start: 1,
        offset: 1,
        size: null,
        scroll: 1,
        visible: null,
        animation: 'normal',
        easing: 'swing',
        auto: 5,
        wrap: null,
        initCallback: null,
        setupCallback: null,
        reloadCallback: null,
        itemLoadCallback: null,
        itemFirstInCallback: null,
        itemFirstOutCallback: null,
        itemLastInCallback: null,
        itemLastOutCallback: null,
        itemVisibleInCallback: null,
        itemVisibleOutCallback: null,
        animationStepCallback: null,
        buttonNextHTML: '<div></div>',
        buttonPrevHTML: '<div></div>',
        buttonNextEvent: 'click',
        buttonPrevEvent: 'click',
        buttonNextCallback: null,
        buttonPrevCallback: null,
        itemFallbackDimension: null
    }, windowLoaded = false;

    $(window).bind('load.jcarousel', function() { windowLoaded = true; });

    /**
     * The jCarousel object.
     *
     * @constructor
     * @class jcarousel
     * @param e {HTMLElement} The element to create the carousel for.
     * @param o {Object} A set of key/value pairs to set as configuration properties.
     * @cat Plugins/jCarousel
     */
    $.jcarousel = function(e, o) {
        this.options    = $.extend({}, defaults, o || {});

        this.locked          = false;
        this.autoStopped     = false;

        this.container       = null;
        this.clip            = null;
        this.list            = null;
        this.buttonNext      = null;
        this.buttonPrev      = null;
        this.buttonNextState = null;
        this.buttonPrevState = null;

        // Only set if not explicitly passed as option
        if (!o || o.rtl === undefined) {
            this.options.rtl = ($(e).attr('dir') || $('html').attr('dir') || '').toLowerCase() == 'rtl';
        }

        this.wh = !this.options.vertical ? 'width' : 'height';
        this.lt = !this.options.vertical ? (this.options.rtl ? 'right' : 'left') : 'top';

        // Extract skin class
        var skin = '', split = e.className.split(' ');

        for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
            if (split[i].indexOf('jcarousel-skin') != -1) {
                $(e).removeClass(split[i]);
                skin = split[i];
                break;
            }
        }

        if (e.nodeName.toUpperCase() == 'UL' || e.nodeName.toUpperCase() == 'OL') {
            this.list      = $(e);
            this.clip      = this.list.parents('.jcarousel-clip');
            this.container = this.list.parents('.jcarousel-container');
        } else {
            this.container = $(e);
            this.list      = this.container.find('ul,ol').eq(0);
            this.clip      = this.container.find('.jcarousel-clip');
        }

        if (this.clip.size() === 0) {
            this.clip = this.list.wrap('<div></div>').parent();
        }

        if (this.container.size() === 0) {
            this.container = this.clip.wrap('<div></div>').parent();
        }

        if (skin !== '' && this.container.parent()[0].className.indexOf('jcarousel-skin') == -1) {
            this.container.wrap('<div class=" '+ skin + '"></div>');
        }

        this.buttonPrev = $('.jcarousel-prev', this.container);

        if (this.buttonPrev.size() === 0 && this.options.buttonPrevHTML !== null) {
            this.buttonPrev = $(this.options.buttonPrevHTML).appendTo(this.container);
        }

        this.buttonPrev.addClass(this.className('jcarousel-prev'));

        this.buttonNext = $('.jcarousel-next', this.container);

        if (this.buttonNext.size() === 0 && this.options.buttonNextHTML !== null) {
            this.buttonNext = $(this.options.buttonNextHTML).appendTo(this.container);
        }

        this.buttonNext.addClass(this.className('jcarousel-next'));

        this.clip.addClass(this.className('jcarousel-clip')).css({
            position: 'relative'
        });

        this.list.addClass(this.className('jcarousel-list')).css({
            overflow: 'hidden',
            position: 'relative',
            top: 0,
            margin: 0,
            padding: 0
        }).css((this.options.rtl ? 'right' : 'left'), 0);

        this.container.addClass(this.className('jcarousel-container')).css({
            position: 'relative'
        });

        if (!this.options.vertical && this.options.rtl) {
            this.container.addClass('jcarousel-direction-rtl').attr('dir', 'rtl');
        }

        var di = this.options.visible !== null ? Math.ceil(this.clipping() / this.options.visible) : null;
        var li = this.list.children('li');

        var self = this;

        if (li.size() > 0) {
            var wh = 0, j = this.options.offset;
            li.each(function() {
                self.format(this, j++);
                wh += self.dimension(this, di);
            });

            this.list.css(this.wh, (wh + 100) + 'px');

            // Only set if not explicitly passed as option
            if (!o || o.size === undefined) {
                this.options.size = li.size();
            }
        }

        // For whatever reason, .show() does not work in Safari...
        this.container.css('display', 'block');
        this.buttonNext.css('display', 'block');
        this.buttonPrev.css('display', 'block');

        this.funcNext   = function() { self.next(); };
        this.funcPrev   = function() { self.prev(); };
        this.funcResize = function() { 
            if (self.resizeTimer) {
                clearTimeout(self.resizeTimer);
            }

            self.resizeTimer = setTimeout(function() {
                self.reload();
            }, 100);
        };

        if (this.options.initCallback !== null) {
            this.options.initCallback(this, 'init');
        }

        if (!windowLoaded && $.browser.safari) {
            this.buttons(false, false);
            $(window).bind('load.jcarousel', function() { self.setup(); });
        } else {
            this.setup();
        }
    };

    // Create shortcut for internal use
    var $jc = $.jcarousel;

    $jc.fn = $jc.prototype = {
        jcarousel: '0.2.8'
    };

    $jc.fn.extend = $jc.extend = $.extend;

    $jc.fn.extend({
        /**
         * Setups the carousel.
         *
         * @method setup
         * @return undefined
         */
        setup: function() {
            this.first       = null;
            this.last        = null;
            this.prevFirst   = null;
            this.prevLast    = null;
            this.animating   = false;
            this.timer       = null;
            this.resizeTimer = null;
            this.tail        = null;
            this.inTail      = false;

            if (this.locked) {
                return;
            }

            this.list.css(this.lt, this.pos(this.options.offset) + 'px');
            var p = this.pos(this.options.start, true);
            this.prevFirst = this.prevLast = null;
            this.animate(p, false);

            $(window).unbind('resize.jcarousel', this.funcResize).bind('resize.jcarousel', this.funcResize);

            if (this.options.setupCallback !== null) {
                this.options.setupCallback(this);
            }
        },

        /**
         * Clears the list and resets the carousel.
         *
         * @method reset
         * @return undefined
         */
        reset: function() {
            this.list.empty();

            this.list.css(this.lt, '0px');
            this.list.css(this.wh, '10px');

            if (this.options.initCallback !== null) {
                this.options.initCallback(this, 'reset');
            }

            this.setup();
        },

        /**
         * Reloads the carousel and adjusts positions.
         *
         * @method reload
         * @return undefined
         */
        reload: function() {
            if (this.tail !== null && this.inTail) {
                this.list.css(this.lt, $jc.intval(this.list.css(this.lt)) + this.tail);
            }

            this.tail   = null;
            this.inTail = false;

            if (this.options.reloadCallback !== null) {
                this.options.reloadCallback(this);
            }

            if (this.options.visible !== null) {
                var self = this;
                var di = Math.ceil(this.clipping() / this.options.visible), wh = 0, lt = 0;
                this.list.children('li').each(function(i) {
                    wh += self.dimension(this, di);
                    if (i + 1 < self.first) {
                        lt = wh;
                    }
                });

                this.list.css(this.wh, wh + 'px');
                this.list.css(this.lt, -lt + 'px');
            }

            this.scroll(this.first, false);
        },

        /**
         * Locks the carousel.
         *
         * @method lock
         * @return undefined
         */
        lock: function() {
            this.locked = true;
            this.buttons();
        },

        /**
         * Unlocks the carousel.
         *
         * @method unlock
         * @return undefined
         */
        unlock: function() {
            this.locked = false;
            this.buttons();
        },

        /**
         * Sets the size of the carousel.
         *
         * @method size
         * @return undefined
         * @param s {Number} The size of the carousel.
         */
        size: function(s) {
            if (s !== undefined) {
                this.options.size = s;
                if (!this.locked) {
                    this.buttons();
                }
            }

            return this.options.size;
        },

        /**
         * Checks whether a list element exists for the given index (or index range).
         *
         * @method get
         * @return bool
         * @param i {Number} The index of the (first) element.
         * @param i2 {Number} The index of the last element.
         */
        has: function(i, i2) {
            if (i2 === undefined || !i2) {
                i2 = i;
            }

            if (this.options.size !== null && i2 > this.options.size) {
                i2 = this.options.size;
            }

            for (var j = i; j <= i2; j++) {
                var e = this.get(j);
                if (!e.length || e.hasClass('jcarousel-item-placeholder')) {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        },

        /**
         * Returns a jQuery object with list element for the given index.
         *
         * @method get
         * @return jQuery
         * @param i {Number} The index of the element.
         */
        get: function(i) {
            return $('>.jcarousel-item-' + i, this.list);
        },

        /**
         * Adds an element for the given index to the list.
         * If the element already exists, it updates the inner html.
         * Returns the created element as jQuery object.
         *
         * @method add
         * @return jQuery
         * @param i {Number} The index of the element.
         * @param s {String} The innerHTML of the element.
         */
        add: function(i, s) {
            var e = this.get(i), old = 0, n = $(s);

            if (e.length === 0) {
                var c, j = $jc.intval(i);
                e = this.create(i);
                while (true) {
                    c = this.get(--j);
                    if (j <= 0 || c.length) {
                        if (j <= 0) {
                            this.list.prepend(e);
                        } else {
                            c.after(e);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                old = this.dimension(e);
            }

            if (n.get(0).nodeName.toUpperCase() == 'LI') {
                e.replaceWith(n);
                e = n;
            } else {
                e.empty().append(s);
            }

            this.format(e.removeClass(this.className('jcarousel-item-placeholder')), i);

            var di = this.options.visible !== null ? Math.ceil(this.clipping() / this.options.visible) : null;
            var wh = this.dimension(e, di) - old;

            if (i > 0 && i < this.first) {
                this.list.css(this.lt, $jc.intval(this.list.css(this.lt)) - wh + 'px');
            }

            this.list.css(this.wh, $jc.intval(this.list.css(this.wh)) + wh + 'px');

            return e;
        },

        /**
         * Removes an element for the given index from the list.
         *
         * @method remove
         * @return undefined
         * @param i {Number} The index of the element.
         */
        remove: function(i) {
            var e = this.get(i);

            // Check if item exists and is not currently visible
            if (!e.length || (i >= this.first && i <= this.last)) {
                return;
            }

            var d = this.dimension(e);

            if (i < this.first) {
                this.list.css(this.lt, $jc.intval(this.list.css(this.lt)) + d + 'px');
            }

            e.remove();

            this.list.css(this.wh, $jc.intval(this.list.css(this.wh)) - d + 'px');
        },

        /**
         * Moves the carousel forwards.
         *
         * @method next
         * @return undefined
         */
        next: function() {
            if (this.tail !== null && !this.inTail) {
                this.scrollTail(false);
            } else {
                this.scroll(((this.options.wrap == 'both' || this.options.wrap == 'last') && this.options.size !== null && this.last == this.options.size) ? 1 : this.first + this.options.scroll);
            }
        },

        /**
         * Moves the carousel backwards.
         *
         * @method prev
         * @return undefined
         */
        prev: function() {
            if (this.tail !== null && this.inTail) {
                this.scrollTail(true);
            } else {
                this.scroll(((this.options.wrap == 'both' || this.options.wrap == 'first') && this.options.size !== null && this.first == 1) ? this.options.size : this.first - this.options.scroll);
            }
        },

        /**
         * Scrolls the tail of the carousel.
         *
         * @method scrollTail
         * @return undefined
         * @param b {Boolean} Whether scroll the tail back or forward.
         */
        scrollTail: function(b) {
            if (this.locked || this.animating || !this.tail) {
                return;
            }

            this.pauseAuto();

            var pos  = $jc.intval(this.list.css(this.lt));

            pos = !b ? pos - this.tail : pos + this.tail;
            this.inTail = !b;

            // Save for callbacks
            this.prevFirst = this.first;
            this.prevLast  = this.last;

            this.animate(pos);
        },

        /**
         * Scrolls the carousel to a certain position.
         *
         * @method scroll
         * @return undefined
         * @param i {Number} The index of the element to scoll to.
         * @param a {Boolean} Flag indicating whether to perform animation.
         */
        scroll: function(i, a) {
            if (this.locked || this.animating) {
                return;
            }

            this.pauseAuto();
            this.animate(this.pos(i), a);
        },

        /**
         * Prepares the carousel and return the position for a certian index.
         *
         * @method pos
         * @return {Number}
         * @param i {Number} The index of the element to scoll to.
         * @param fv {Boolean} Whether to force last item to be visible.
         */
        pos: function(i, fv) {
            var pos  = $jc.intval(this.list.css(this.lt));

            if (this.locked || this.animating) {
                return pos;
            }

            if (this.options.wrap != 'circular') {
                i = i < 1 ? 1 : (this.options.size && i > this.options.size ? this.options.size : i);
            }

            var back = this.first > i;

            // Create placeholders, new list width/height
            // and new list position
            var f = this.options.wrap != 'circular' && this.first <= 1 ? 1 : this.first;
            var c = back ? this.get(f) : this.get(this.last);
            var j = back ? f : f - 1;
            var e = null, l = 0, p = false, d = 0, g;

            while (back ? --j >= i : ++j < i) {
                e = this.get(j);
                p = !e.length;
                if (e.length === 0) {
                    e = this.create(j).addClass(this.className('jcarousel-item-placeholder'));
                    c[back ? 'before' : 'after' ](e);

                    if (this.first !== null && this.options.wrap == 'circular' && this.options.size !== null && (j <= 0 || j > this.options.size)) {
                        g = this.get(this.index(j));
                        if (g.length) {
                            e = this.add(j, g.clone(true));
                        }
                    }
                }

                c = e;
                d = this.dimension(e);

                if (p) {
                    l += d;
                }

                if (this.first !== null && (this.options.wrap == 'circular' || (j >= 1 && (this.options.size === null || j <= this.options.size)))) {
                    pos = back ? pos + d : pos - d;
                }
            }

            // Calculate visible items
            var clipping = this.clipping(), cache = [], visible = 0, v = 0;
            c = this.get(i - 1);
            j = i;

            while (++visible) {
                e = this.get(j);
                p = !e.length;
                if (e.length === 0) {
                    e = this.create(j).addClass(this.className('jcarousel-item-placeholder'));
                    // This should only happen on a next scroll
                    if (c.length === 0) {
                        this.list.prepend(e);
                    } else {
                        c[back ? 'before' : 'after' ](e);
                    }

                    if (this.first !== null && this.options.wrap == 'circular' && this.options.size !== null && (j <= 0 || j > this.options.size)) {
                        g = this.get(this.index(j));
                        if (g.length) {
                            e = this.add(j, g.clone(true));
                        }
                    }
                }

                c = e;
                d = this.dimension(e);
                if (d === 0) {
                    throw new Error('jCarousel: No width/height set for items. This will cause an infinite loop. Aborting...');
                }

                if (this.options.wrap != 'circular' && this.options.size !== null && j > this.options.size) {
                    cache.push(e);
                } else if (p) {
                    l += d;
                }

                v += d;

                if (v >= clipping) {
                    break;
                }

                j++;
            }
```

Comment: There is even a link to docs in comments, please read them , there's a lot of useful info in  there http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/docs/reference/configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

what you have provided is the plugin source code. Find the code which initializes the carousel. it will look something similar to

```
$('#jcarousel').jcarousel({
    list: '.jcarousel-list'
});
```

you can pass an object property called `wrap`. so the final code will look something like

```
$('#jcarousel').jcarousel({
    wrap: 'circular'
});
```

[Here](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/docs/reference/configuration.html#wrap) you can find the documentation for this